# Disable ActiveAdmin login for accessing home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm trying to disable the initial redirect to the login page in my Rails (4.1) app but i can't figure out how i can do that. I want my app to be visibile anyway without authentication and just make it required to access the admin area.

Do i have to act at routes level or it's a matter of ActiveAdmin configuration?

Thank you very much.

I've googled and search here without success

Comment: Just don't understand how do you authenticate users. If you are using devise for authentication and have before_filters, make sure you write an except for the index action. If anything else then add it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to disable authentication somewhere, just ensure you have set before_filter in `application_controller.rb` right:

`before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]` #any action here would mean skipping authentication on it